# How can I achieve this design with flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[I tried using tab bar to solve it but it didn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ff3N.png)

Comment: Please provide, the code that you have done.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you have already tried

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? is this just a row with buttons/labels/badges? Please explain a bit more what is the end goal.

Comment: Please provide some explanation for us to understand your problem. Here, we can not understand what you are trying to achieve. Whether you want to keep like tabs, or just a row of buttons?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`ClipRRect`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRRect-class.html) widget:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text(
                  'Healthy',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10,
            ),
            ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text(
                  'Healthy',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
Row(
            children: [
              //unselected Chip
              ActionChip(
                onPressed: (){

                },
                shape: StadiumBorder(side: BorderSide()),
                label: Text("History"),
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              ),
              //selected Chip
              ActionChip(
                onPressed: (){

                },
                label: Text("Funny Stories"),
                shape: StadiumBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange)),
                backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
              )
            ],
          ),
```

output : [image]